# How to handle exception/error while dividing two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv below

```
A,B
1,0
1,1
1,-
10,5
```

Here my expected out is

```
A,B,C
1,0,0
1,1,1
1,-,0
10,5,2.0
```

If Value error or exception came then output of `C` is `0`. means i need to divide `df['A'] / df['B']`
DO I need to write a function for this using `try except` or in pandas is there any option is there?

Comment: replace the `-` and convert `B` to an `int` then divide

Comment: You need to handle converting your B column into numeric first then attempt to do the mathematical operation.  You can do this as @YOBEN_S shows in that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.to_numeric` +`fillna`

```
df['C']=df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').fillna(0).eval('A*B')
df
   A  B    C
0  1  0  0.0
1  1  1  1.0
2  1  -  0.0
```

Comment: invalid syntax at the end

Comment: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: @Nons `df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')` did you run this ?

Comment: `df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')` is working but when i want add `df['c'] = df[['A','B']].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')`, its throwing error, i have some othere columns also which has to intact

Comment: @Nons where is my eval ?